# Which PHP framework is more suitable for an enterprise project?

Tags: php

Our company decided to create an enterprise project (a warehouse management web application).

Now my responsibility is to choose the best PHP framework that has great support and features to do this project. During the past week I researched some popular PHP frameworks (laravel, yii, symfony, Zend framework) but I want to make sure which one is best suited for this work.

Can anyone help?! The features that are most important are long term support, reliability, almost easy to learn (but we are not beginners in PHP), good documentation, security and stability.

Comment: you might some useful information here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/what-security-features-should-a-php-framework-have?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Trends for this data is interesting as a starting point.

[image: Google Trends Data for 5 PHP Framework terms]

Any of these frameworks though are legitimate contenders (I added Codeigniter as well).

**List what you need and compare** - It is good practice to create a matrix with these issues (the ones you outlined in your question) that are important to the project.  Also add to that the necessary features of the project, what the project is actually going to do and components will be needed to do that.  Then go through the frameworks and make an educated guess about how they stack up.

**Try out some quick dev** - Then spend a little bit of time (a few days or maybe a weekend) building a dev environment where you and some of your team see how easily you can get a couple of these frameworks up and running on a test server or two with a feature or two that your project is going to need.   As you look at what code is available to build on, and look at how you get it running you will get a sense from you and your php devs which ones are suited for your team and project.  As a bonus you will have more buy-in from your team as they are part of the process.

This link has a nice rationale for each framework. https://webinerds.com/choose-php-application-framework/

Check Google for CVEs (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures) for good context about the type of security issues that the framework has historically.

Having said all of that, personally if I were tackling that kind of project I would rank them from best to worst (getting the best project out the door the quickest) as Yii and Symfony (because of more contributed code you could use) followed by Laravel and Codeigniter with Zend in last place because of complexity.